# Error when trusting HTTPS certificate using okhttp in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-android-extensions

I have found many related questions on this and I have tried many options. But I'm not able to resolve it. I want to disable certification checking on making an API call using `okhttp`.

**Below is the code that I tried**

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager

    class UnsafeOkHttpClient {
    companion object {
        fun getUnsafeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient.Builder {
            try {
                // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
                    }

                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
                    }

                    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> {
                        return arrayOf()
                    }
                })

                // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
                sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
                // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
                val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

                val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
                builder.hostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }

                return builder
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**On making request**:

```
 fun getAppList(requestbody: AppListRequestBody, baseUrl: String): AppListResponse {

        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val appListRequestInfo: String = gson.toJson(requestbody)
        val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json")
        val appListBody: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, appListRequestInfo)
        val client =getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build

        var appListRequest: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url("$baseUrl/apps/mobile")
                .post(appListBody)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build()
        val appResponse: Response = client.newCall(appListRequest).execute() //Getting syntax error
        if (!appResponse.isSuccessful) {
            Log.e("Exception =",appResponse.message())
            throw Exception(appResponse.code().toString())
        }
        Log.d("App list res",appResponse.body().toString())
        return Gson().fromJson(appResponse.body()!!.string(), AppListResponse::class.java)
    }
```

**I'm getting an exception:**

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found}
```

Please help me with this.Also, why does it show protocol as http when the url is https? Is there any ways to set that. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue was with the request body. Mapping the data class with the request body had some issues.That's why it was showing 404 error. Anyways got it resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your `getUnsafeOkHttpClient()` returns an `OkHttpClient.Builder`.

Replace

```
    val client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
```

with

```
    val client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build()
```

Comment: Thanks, syntax error is gone but still I get exception as Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found,